# Placeholder get first word and ignore others

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have this js code :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Ticket = require('../models/Ticket');
const db = require("../models/deskmodedb");
const Ocorrencia = require('../models/Ocorrencia');

router.get('/detalhes-ticket/:cod_ticket', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Request Id:', req.params.cod_ticket);
    var ticketControl;

    ticketControl = Ticket.sync().then(function() {
        return db.sequelize.query(
            'SELECT cod_ticket, titulo_ticket, descricao_ticket, status_ticket, tipo_ticket, data_abertura FROM ticket WHERE cod_ticket IN  (:codigo_ticket) ', {
                replacements: { codigo_ticket: req.params.cod_ticket },
                type: db.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
            })
    }).then((tickets) => {
        ticketControl = tickets
    }).catch((err) => { console.log('error' + err) })
    ocorrenciaControl = Ocorrencia.sync().then(function() {
        return db.sequelize.query(
            'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cod_ocorrencia ASC) AS Row, cod_ticket_f, conteudo_ocorrencia, cod_ocorrencia,data_ocorrencia FROM ocorrencia WHERE cod_ticket_f IN (:codigo_ticket) ', {
                replacements: { codigo_ticket: req.params.cod_ticket },
                type: db.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
            }).then((ocorrenciaControl) => {
            res.render('detalhesTicket', {
                tickets: ticketControl,
                ocorrencias: ocorrenciaControl,
                style: 'global.css'
            })
        })
    })
})
```

I get a ticket (Line in my ticket table) and get a ocorrence with the ticket number and send for my page detalhesTicket.handlebars.

In my detalhesTicket.handlebars i show the values with **{{variable}}**:

```
{{#each tickets}}
         <h1 class="text-light">
            Detalhes do Ticket <span id="cod_ticket">#{{cod_ticket}}</span>
         </h1>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <!-- Cabeçalho Ticket -->
   <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="col-10">
         <label for="titulo_ticket" class="form-label">Titulo do ticket</label>
         <input  type="text" class="form-control bg-light mb-2" id="titulo_ticket" placeholder={{titulo_ticket}} disabled>
         <label for="descricao_ticket" class="form-label">Descrição do ticket</label>
         <textarea class="form-control bg-light" id="descricao_ticket" rows="4" disabled>{{descricao_ticket}}</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
         <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-12 mx-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" type="button" id="tempo_aberto">
            {{data_abertura}}
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" type="button" id="status_ticket">
            {{status_ticket}}
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" type="button" id="tipo_ticket">
            {{tipo_ticket}}
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" type="button" id="setor_usuario">
            Setor do usuário
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" type="button" id="nome_usuario">
            Nome do usuário
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" type="button" id="email_usuario">
            Email do usuário
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <hr>
   {{/each}}
   {{!-- O each da ocorrencia começa aqui  --}}
   {{#each ocorrencias}}
   <!-- Ocorrências -->
   <div class="mt-3">
      <div class="ocorrencia mb-3">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
               <label for="titulo_ticket" class="form-label">Ocorrência <span id="cod_ocorrencia">#{{Row}}</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-auto">
               <span id="data_ocorrencia">{{data_ocorrencia}} </span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <input type="text"  class="form-control bg-light" id="titulo_ticket" placeholder={{conteudo_ocorrencia}} disabled>
      </div>
   </div>
   <hr>
   {{!-- E terminaria aqui  --}}
   {{/each}}
```

My variable conteudo_ocorrencia has the value "aucto nunc nulla vulputate". When i render my page to show the value the value apper in this format:

[image]

My corret value need be plaseholder"aucto nunc nulla vulputate". How to add my all variable valor in plaseholder ?

Comment: use quotes `placeholder="{{titulo_ticket}}"`

Comment: Work. thanks. Please put this in a answer for me mark the problem with solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use quotes like this:

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control bg-light" id="titulo_ticket" placeholder="{{conteudo_ocorrencia}}" disabled>
```